# Book about time-travel engineer going rogue

Tags: story-identification, books, time-travel, engineering

Looking for a name of the book I read while ago - it was sci-fi book about time travel; initial time frame is 2300-3000, I think. Gist of it is the main character was a low-mid tier engineer, responsible for (as far as I remember) the set up of a time travel procedure (which was mainly used for scientific purposes and for prevention of big, time-related disasters). After some events, he slowly climbed ranks, eventually found a woman he likes (she was from higher ranks also, I think), but they couldn't be together, so eventually they ran away in the far future (time travel in that book worked both ways), where people were not allowed to travel.

Some more key points that I remember:

- It was a time where time travel was already invented long time ago, but it was still a difficult and dangerous procedure because of possible time paradoxes.
- It was possible to travel both backwards and forwards, but there were periods of time where people were not allowed to travel (and it was physically impossible to travel to time before the invention of the time machine).
- Job of main character was related to correction of events in different timespans (to prevent disasters), with a goal of making minimal impact on other timespans.
- There was a part in the book where the main character would closely encounter version of himself in a different time.

Hope it's enough information, really want to read this book again.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Sounds like this might be *[The End of Eternity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_End_of_Eternity)* by Isaac Asimov.

[image]

Excerpt from [a review](https://www.sfsite.com/10b/ee91.htm) at SF Site:

> The End of Eternity concerns **Andrew Harlan, a Technician for the organization called Eternity**. As a Technician, Harlan is an expert at determining and executing the Minimum Necessary Change in a timeline to attain a desired Change in history. For **the Eternals, men who live "outside Time," monitor human history from the 27th century to about the 70,000th century, trying to maintain a stable society, with reasonable prosperity**. They allow some trade between centuries, but for the most part they work at eliminating worrisome trends: excessively unusual social mores, dangerous technology such as atomic weapons, and, to be sure, excessive curiosity about the nature of Eternity.
>
> As the book opens Harlan is shown committing a crime: in exchange for concealing a minor error by a functionary of one of the Eternity bases, he arranges to have the Life Plot of a certain woman tracked through a change. For, you see, when Reality Changes, everybody changes with it. And a woman you loved might suddenly be married, or have suffered an accident, or be altered in personality.
>
> Flashbacks then show Harlan's history: his recruitment from a somewhat conservative century, his early career as an Eternal, **his interest in Primitive history (from before the invention of time travel, thus before Eternity can manipulate history)**. Finally he encounters the alluring Noÿs Lambent, a woman of a sexually loose century, and the stiff, inexperienced Harlan falls in love, and before long is ready to risk the very existence of Eternity to keep his woman.

The full story can be read [here](https://novels80.com/the-end-of-eternity/1-technician-996066.html).

Comment: Yes! Thank you, exactly what was I looking for, can't believe I forgot that it's Asimov's book